# Literal strings Corona Lua

Tags: string, lua

Estou meio perdido com o uso do `\t`. No console, ele funciona e no simulador ele é ignorado. Se alguém souber de uma possível solução.

```
local myText = display.newText("a\tb", 200, 100, native.systemFont, 16)
print(myText.text)
```

Ou:

```
a = "oi"
b = "teste"
local myText = display.newText(a.."\t"..b, 200, 100, native.systemFont, 16)
print(myText.text)
```